# Get the wrong href link when do Edit as HTML

Tags: web-scraping, href, urlencode, htmlunit, web-inspector

I'm using HTMLUnit to extract href attributes under anchor class elements from Google Shopping results. To get a list of all the URLs of the shopping results, I use:

```
List<HtmlElement> urls = page.getByXPath("//a[contains(@class,'Lq5OHe eaGTj translate-content')]");
```

but some of the links turned out to be wrong, or more accurately, distorted. For example: this is the link I was supposed to retrieve based on what I saw using Inspect

https://www.universitysupplystore.com/shop_product_detail.asp?catalog_group_id=MjE&catalog_group_name=VGlkZSBUZWNo&catalog_id=599&catalog_name=TWFjQm9vaw&pf_id=202680&product_name=MTMtSW5jaCBNYWNib29rIEFpciBBcHBsZSBNMiBDaGlwIFdpdGggOC1Db3JlIENwdSBBbmQgOC1Db3JlIEdwdS84R2IgVW5pZmllZCBNZW1vcnk&type=1&target=shop_product_list.asp

but this is what the scraper got **(not working link)**

https://www.universitysupplystore.com/shop_product_detail.asp%3Fcatalog_group_id%3DMjE%26catalog_group_name%3DVGlkZSBUZWNo%26catalog_id%3D599%26catalog_name%3DTWFjQm9vaw%26pf_id%3D202680%26product_name%3DMTMtSW5jaCBNYWNib29rIEFpciBBcHBsZSBNMiBDaGlwIFdpdGggOC1Db3JlIENwdSBBbmQgOC1Db3JlIEdwdS84R2IgVW5pZmllZCBNZW1vcnk%26type%3D1%26target%3Dshop_product_list.asp&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwjtzMqfoLD5AhVIBUQIHXbUBmoQ2SkIww4&usg=AOvVaw2Bom-oAHHYL7PLWixwFHes

And this is the href link when I clicked "Edit as HTML" on the Elements tab after Inspect. **(not working link)**
https://www.universitysupplystore.com/shop_product_detail.asp%3Fcatalog_group_id%3DMjE%26catalog_group_name%3DVGlkZSBUZWNo%26catalog_id%3D599%26catalog_name%3DTWFjQm9vaw%26pf_id%3D202680%26product_name%3DMTMtSW5jaCBNYWNib29rIEFpciBBcHBsZSBNMiBDaGlwIFdpdGggOC1Db3JlIENwdSBBbmQgOC1Db3JlIEdwdS84R2IgVW5pZmllZCBNZW1vcnk%26type%3D1%26target%3Dshop_product_list.asp&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&sa=U&ved=0ahUKEwiDjOz0oLD5AhU2KkQIHdZJDjAQ2SkIjxY&usg=AOvVaw0l1Boo5XTmiOrL3GU8XMuq

My observation is that it added different characters like % to the original link. My goal is to extract this original link. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

What you are facing here is more or less URL encoding (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding).

Please clarify what you are mean by 'not working link'. What do you try to do with the URL?

Comment: like when I open it it's not the same as the original link. The original link has the valid result but this link opens to a not found one

Comment: Ok, i see - can you please open an issue at gitbub (https://github.com/HtmlUnit/htmlunit/issues).
Looks like a closer look is required.